# How to get specifiy String in ArrayList for comparion if-else

Tags: java, android, if-statement, arraylist

I have a list like this :
[image]
now, i want to use it, if the `text1 = "A12345"`, then do something.

if the `text1 = "B54321"`, do otherwise
but i've tried like below, but it did not work,
 how should i do that

```
private void buildRecyclerView(){
        // Create recycler view.
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        // Create an adapter and supply the data to be displayed.
        mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(mExampleList);

        // Give the recycler view a default layout manager.
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // Connect the adapter with the recycler view.
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        //buat hilang dulu diawal
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, mRecyclerView ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(menu_utama.this, "Clicked at pos " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (getText(0) == "A12345"){
                            // do here
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        // do whatever
                    }
                })
        );
    }
```

Comment: use `equals()` method for String comparison.

Comment: in my case in ArrayList, how to get string from ArrayList and compare it, is it like this : getText(0).equals("/A12345")